# Laravel backpack InlineCreate Operation Method not allowed error

Tags: laravel-backpack, laravel-9

Trying to use inline_create i can create in modal but i can't select i get error

> Method not allowed The POST method is not supported for this route.
> Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

URL is : http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/question/fetch/tags

```
Field

$this->crud->addField(
            [
                'label' => "Les mote clé",
                'minimum_input_length' => 0,
                'type'      => 'relationship',
                'name'      => 'tags', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                'ajax' => true,
                // 'method'                  => 'GET',
                'minimum_input_length' => 0,
                'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
                'inline_create' =>  [ // specify the entity in singular
                    'entity' => 'tag', // the entity in singular
                    'force_select' => true, // should the inline-created entry be immediately selected?
                    'modal_class' => 'modal-dialog modal-md', // use modal-sm, modal-lg to change width
                    'modal_route' => route('tag-inline-create'), // InlineCreate::getInlineCreateModal()
                    'create_route' =>  route('tag-inline-create-save'), // InlineCreate::storeInlineCreate()
                ]  
            ]
        );

Question modal 

// tags 
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'question_tags', 'question_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem.
I needed to define the ajax route to work with the field, either creating my own endpoin, or using `FetchOperation` https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-fetch#about-1.

In `QuestionCrudController`:

```php
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\FetchOperation;
...

    public function fetchTags()
    {
       return $this->fetch(Tag::class);
    }
```